# Correct usage of your

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct usage of your in the following please:  Attached for your and dan's review

Answer (score 0):

I would go the business style:

**Attached for the Review of:  Mr. Miller and Mr. Simon**

Answer (score -1):

This phrase is awkward because it puts a pronoun and a proper name in parallel.

A smoother wording might be the following:

> Attached for review by Dan and yourself.

Comment: Except _yourself_ is a reflexive pronoun, which is uncalled for in this sentence.